# Haskell function to verify parentheses matching

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, stack

I need to write a function `par :: String -> Bool` to verify if a given string with parentheses is matching using stack module.

Ex:

```
par "(((()[()])))" = True
par "((]())" = False
```

Here's my stack module implementation:

```
module Stack (Stack,
              push, pop, top,
              empty, isEmpty)
    where

data Stack a = Stk [a]
             deriving (Show)

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (Stk xs) = Stk (x:xs)

pop :: Stack a -> Stack a
pop (Stk (_:xs)) = Stk xs
pop _ = error "Stack.pop: empty stack"


top :: Stack a -> a
top (Stk (x:_)) = x
top _ = error "Stack.top: empty stack"

empty :: Stack a
empty = Stk []

isEmpty :: Stack a -> Bool
isEmpty (Stk [])= True
isEmpty (Stk _) = False
```

So I need to implement a `par` function that would test a string of parentheses and say if the parentheses in it are balanced or not. How can I do that using a stack?

Comment: The question is how to write the par function.
I only have a stack implementation here.

Comment: Rizo, then explain that in your question.

Comment: At which level do you have a problem ?
You simply have to iterate on the string, character per character, pushing each opening parenthesis, brace or bracket on the stack and when encountering a closing element, pop the one on top of the stack, and check it is of the same kind as the closing one.
Looks like homework, no ?

Comment: Is it homework? Why not return a `Maybe a` in `pop` and `top`?

Comment: It is! :-)
All done! I was trying to implement an erroneous algorithm.

Comment: I need `pop` to return a resulting stack, not an element (see my answer).
But top is returning `a` of any type (without Maybe)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
module Parens where

import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

matchingParens :: Map Char Char
matchingParens = Map.fromList [
    ('(', ')')
  , ('{', '}')
  , ('[', ']')
  ]

isOpening :: Char -> Bool
isOpening c = maybe False (const True) $ Map.lookup c matchingParens

type Stack a = [a]

balanced :: String -> Bool
balanced = balanced' []

balanced' :: Stack Char -> String -> Bool
balanced' [] ""     = True
balanced' _  ""     = False
balanced' [] (c:cs) = balanced' [c] cs
balanced' (o:os) (c:cs)
  | isOpening c = balanced' (c:o:os) cs
  | otherwise   = case Map.lookup o matchingParens of
      Nothing -> False
      Just closing -> if closing == c
        then balanced' os cs
        else False
```

Comment: By the way, `isOpening c = Map.member c matchingParens`.  Hoogle is your friend!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer:

```
parent' :: String -> Stack Char -> Bool
parent' [] stk = isEmpty stk
parent' (c:str) stk
        | (c == '(') = parent' str (push c stk)
        | (c == ')') = if isEmpty stk then False
                       else if top stk == '(' then parent' str (pop stk)
                       else False



parent :: String -> Bool
parent [] = True
parent str = parent' str empty
```

Comment: That will not work for other parentheses such as '['/']', '{','}' etcetera and will break when you give it a string with other characters mixed in. But you're definitely on the right track!

Answer (score 3):

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

parse :: String -> Maybe String
parse xs@(')':_) = return xs
parse xs@(']':_) = return xs
parse ('(':xs) = do
  ')':ys <- parse xs
  parse ys
parse ('[':xs) = do
  ']':ys <- parse xs
  parse ys
parse (_:xs) = parse xs
parse [] = return []

paren :: String -> Bool
paren xs = isJust $ do
  ys <- parse xs
  guard (null ys)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a haskell newbie. Here's my attempt, definitely inelegant but wanted to try a different approach

```
data Stack a = Stk [a]
         deriving (Show)

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (Stk xs) = Stk (x:xs)

pop :: Stack a -> (Maybe a, Stack a)
pop (Stk []) = (Nothing, Stk [])
pop (Stk (x:xs)) = (Just x, Stk xs)

top :: Stack a -> Maybe a
top (Stk (x:_)) = Just x
top _ = Nothing

empty :: Stack a
empty = Stk []

isEmpty :: Stack a -> Bool
isEmpty (Stk [])= True
isEmpty (Stk _) = False 


par :: String -> Maybe (Stack Char)
par = foldl check (Just (Stk []))
      where check (Just stk) x
                | x == '(' = Just (push x stk)
                | x == ')' = case pop stk of
                                     (Just '(', newStk) -> Just newStk
                                     _ -> Nothing
            check Nothing x = Nothing


parCheck :: String -> Bool
parCheck xs = case par xs of
                Just stk -> isEmpty stk
                Nothing -> False
```

Comment: You can simplify `if isEmpty stk then True else False` to `isEmpty stk`, `x \`elem\` "("` to `x == '('`, and `(Just topElem, newStk) -> if topElem == '(' then Just newStk else Nothing; (Nothing,_) -> Nothing` to `(Just '(', newStk) -> Just newStk; _ -> Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

```haskell
parent :: String -> Bool
parent "" = True
parent str = verify str empty

verify :: String -> Stack Char -> Bool
verify [] stk = isEmpty stk
verify (c:str) stk
        | (c == '(') = verify str (push c stk)
        | (c == ')') = if isEmpty stk then False else if top stk == '(' then verify str (pop stk) else False
        | (c == '[') = verify str (push c stk)
        | (c == ']') = if isEmpty stk then False else if top stk == '[' then verify str (pop stk) else False
```

Comment: Worked on your solution @rizo

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.Char

verifier :: String -> Bool
verifier x = balancer x []
    where
balancer [] stack = null stack
balancer (x:xs) [] = balancer xs [x]
balancer (x:xs) (y:ys)  = if isSpace x then balancer xs (y:ys)
              else if x `elem` "([{" then balancer xs (x:y:ys)
                  else if (x == ')' && y == '(') ||  
                  (x == ']' && y == '[') || 
                  (x == '}' && y == '{')  then balancer xs ys 
                else False
```

Comment: Give explanation also.

Comment: @SujithPS We start with an empty stack. Push an opening bracket when it appears, and if a closed bracket appears check if the top of the stack contains the matching opening bracket. If it does, pop it and proceed, otherwise report error. At the end of parsing, if the stack is empty it's a valid sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
isOpenBracket :: Char -> Bool
isOpenBracket x = case x of 
    '{' -> True
    '[' -> True
    '(' -> True
    otherwise -> False  

isCloseBracket :: Char -> Bool
isCloseBracket x = case x of 
    '}' -> True
    ']' -> True
    ')' -> True
    otherwise -> False 

bracketLookup :: Char -> Char
bracketLookup x = case x of 
    '{' -> '}'
    '[' -> ']'
    '(' -> ')'

checkBrackets :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool 
checkBrackets [] []             = True
checkBrackets [] (x:xs)         = (isOpenBracket x) && (checkBrackets (x:[]) (xs))
checkBrackets (s:ss) (x:xs) 
    | (isOpenBracket x)         = (checkBrackets (x:s:ss) (xs))
    | (isCloseBracket x)        = (x == bracketLookup s) && checkBrackets (ss) (xs)
    -- case where x is not a a bracket (invalid char), just skip it
    | otherwise                 = checkBrackets (s:ss) (xs) 
checkBrackets (x:xs) [] = False

bracketParity x = checkBrackets "" x
```

My attempt, just using a list as a stack and rercusing along the input. Ignores non-bracket characters.

Outputs:

```
*Main> bracketParity "{()([a])}"
True
*Main> bracketParity "{()([aaaa])}"
True
*Main> bracketParity "{(a)([aaaa]a)}"
True
*Main> bracketParity "{()([])}"
True
*Main> bracketParity "[][][]"
True
*Main> bracketParity "[][][]]"
False
```